# Stricter union types when using mapped types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, types, discriminated-union, union-types, mapped-types

I'm attempting to use a mapped type to provide more type safety when using union types in a map. There does not seem to be a way to provide type safety between the key/value when using a property type (e.g. `['value']`) as the type for the key (`K`).

I would like to avoid creating a unique model by hand to allow for this.

*Code:*

```
interface IAction { value: string; }

type ActionMapper<A extends IAction> = {
   [K in A['value']]: A;
}

interface IActionOne { value: 'action_one' }

interface IActionTwo { value: 'action_two' }

type Actions = IActionOne | IActionTwo;

const reducerMap: ActionMapper<Actions> = {
  action_one: { value: 'action_one' },
  action_two: { value: 'action_one' }, // expecting this line to fail
}
```

I have commented the line I expected to fail.

I feel I should be able to leverage the key (`K in`) to provide the correct type as the value. However, I currently use `A`, which provides the `IAction` implementation where the `value` is of type `string` - I want to avoid this.

Is this possible in the current version of TypeScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do what you want.

As you note, your problem is that the values of properties of `ActionMapper<A>` is always `A`.  For `Actions`, that's a union type.  What you really want to do is extract from `A` the constituent that matches `{value: K}` for each key `K`.  Luckily, there is a [pre-defined conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#predefined-conditional-types) named [`Extract`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.0.1/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1391-L1394) that does this for you.  Let's redefine `ActionMapper<A>`:

```
type ActionMapper<A extends IAction> = {
   [K in A['value']]: Extract<A, {value: K}>;
}
```

Now we will try again:

```
const reducerMap: ActionMapper<Actions> = {
  action_one: { value: 'action_one' },
  action_two: { value: 'action_one' }, // error!
  // Type '"action_one"' is not assignable to type '"action_two"'.
}
```

And you get the error you expected.  Hope that helps.  Good luck!